# How to Create Global Contacts Directory for Microsoft Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange-server

I have a requirement from one of our Clients where he wants
to Create a Global Contacts Directory in Microsoft Exchange Server.
Let, me explain this. Suppose, there is some Company say "X".
And, it has some Employees. Each Employee will have his/her contacts in their mailing list. So, the Global Contacts Directory 
should consists of All the Contacts of these Employees. And it should Also
Sync them.
Is this feasible enough is what i want to know and if Yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box? No. Is using a PF folder or a shared mailbox an option? Each user can have his/her own contacts folder.

Comment: Can you please explain what you really want to say? I did not get you

Comment: You can create folders for each user in the Public Folders store that all users will see in their profiles.